# I’m creating a birthday reminder app in flutter, I’ve done everything except setting schedule notification on the specific date of birth Enter by user

Tags: flutter, schedule, dart-pub, reminders, flutter-notification

I’ve implemented these things

1. Databas.
2. showing the records in list view
3. There’s a add button to add user             name, date of birth
4. Local notification as well

Problem is ,how to setup notification reminder on the specific date enter by the user so that the app remind me the birthday of the person

Comment: Please help me to do this assignment

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try below easy dependency.
https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications

```
  String localTimeZone = await AwesomeNotifications().getLocalTimeZoneIdentifier();
  String utcTimeZone = await AwesomeNotifications().getLocalTimeZoneIdentifier();
  
  await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
      content: NotificationContent(
          id: id,
          channelKey: 'scheduled',
          title: 'Notification at every single minute',
          body:
              'This notification was schedule to repeat at every single minute.',
          notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.BigPicture,
          bigPicture: 'asset://assets/images/melted-clock.png'),
      schedule: NotificationInterval(interval: /*Your Interval in Seconds (60)*/, timeZone: localTimeZone, repeats: true));
```

Comment: Sir could you suggest me any tutorail for this problem. I tried but did not implement.

Comment: @FaridGem Please check below repository https://github.com/sentanilesh/schedule_notification_fluttrer

Comment: Sir I know how to schedule a notification on a specific time, like you did in the app, after 10 sec a notification displayed but my problem is how to set a Birthday reminder. Suppose I enter my date of birth 8/9/2002, and tomorrow on 9/9/2021 it reminds me that it is your birthday.

Comment: @FaridGem In this case you can manually add time difference and schedule the notification please check https://github.com/sentanilesh/schedule_notification_fluttrer/commit/df37492b9ee5edda21bf8b44bf24a248649a45ec

Comment: Thank You Sir! but I'm still stuck on it because I don't get any notification with the current date I entered manually. please help me. +923345850933 on whatsApp